# VUE JS: How to keep same structure in whole project but different header and footer for each page

Tags: vue.js

I am using router-view. In App.vue I want this structure so in every other pages I can have different header, footer but overall structure:

```
    <router-view>
          <template>
            <div class="container">
              <header>
                <slot name="header"></slot>
              </header>
              <main>
                <slot></slot>
              </main>
              <footer>
                <slot name="footer"></slot>
              </footer>
            </div>
          </template>
        </router-view>

In home page component I want to do something like this:
<slot name="header">header content</slot>
<slot name="footer">footer content</slot>
Othercontent here....

In about us page component I want to do something like this:
<slot name="header">about header content</slot>
<slot name="footer">about footer content</slot>
Othercontent here....

how can I achive this?
```

Comment: This is explained in the docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#named-slots

Answer (score 1):

The solution goes around layouts and sub-pages where layouts are parents and related pages placed as children.

Consider these two layouts:

```js
// src/layouts/PublicLayout.vue
<template>
  <section class="public-layout">
    <router-view/>
  </section>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'PublicLayout',
};
</script>
```

and

```js
// src/layouts/MainLayout.vue
<template>
  <section class="main-layout">
    <!-- header -->
    <router-view/>
    <!-- footer -->
  </section>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'MainLayout',
};
</script>
```

Now, you can tune `routes` in your flavor:

```js
// src/router/index.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

const publicRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/public',
    component: () => import('layouts/PublicLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: () => import('pages/ULogin.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: 'sign-up',
        name: 'SignUp',
        component: () => import('pages/USignUp.vue'),
      },
    ],
  },
];
const mainRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'Home',
        component: () => import('pages/UHome.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        name: 'Profile',
        component: () => import('pages/Profile.vue'),
      },
    ],
  },
];

const Router = new VueRouter({   
    routes: mainRoutes.concat(publicRoutes),
});

// snippet skipped
```

Here, `MainLayout` and `PublicLayout` play the structural role while other pages are placed as their children. By navigating to each page (e.g. from `/login` to `/profile`) the proper layout will get loaded as well.

Comment: I am asking different question. 
I want to have basic layout like 3 tags header, footer and main in App.vue
what I want is I want to place different content inside those 3 tags for each page.
So layout will be same but content inside that layout will be different.

Comment: I am fully aware. There is no better way to implement that than layouts. You'd better leave the `App` component empty (just a `<router-view/>` tag) and then define your layouts according to your will (some have a sidebar, some have the footer, ...) and place pages under the proper layout. Of course, routes can be a tree with any level of depth. 
Trying slots you will fail before starting.

Answer (score 0):

```
<your-base-layout>
   <slot #header>about header content</slot>
   <slot #footer>about footer content</slot>
</your-base-layout>
```

its called "Named Slot"

Comment: But this doesnot work. I already tried it. I am using <router-view/> in App.vue